# Are attachment, aversion, ignorance Kamma?

Tags: theravada

Are attachment, aversion, ignorance Kamma?
Are they leading to a bad destination?
If they are not Kamma how do they lead you to a bad destination?

Answer (score 2):

There are three types of kamma, namely, bodily, verbal & mental (refer to AN 6.63).

As soon as intention & attachment arise in the mind, this is mental kamma & such mental kamma will have a result or destination.

For example, by mere thinking alone, a neurotic person may have a psychiatric hospital as their destination.

Therefore, as soon as ignorance & aversion result in intention & attachment, this is kamma.

Answer (score 1):

Well kamma is basically "action", so your attachment, aversion and ignorance certainly can lead to actions. If the actions are bad they have the potential to lead you to bad destinations.

Answer (score 1):

Ignorance is the root cause for immoral/unfruitful actions and thoughts, forming fresh kamma in the process. The worst of its kind are immoral acts like killing, stealing, etc that are responsible for the worst outcomes, the worst kinds of future suffering; these are the worst forms of sankhara.

Attachment and its opposite, aversion, too generate akusala kamma, and one can see the results of such in this very life. For example, when we get attached to things or people via strong attachments or strong dislikes, that leads to mental suffering in this very life. One can even commit murder due to anger that is done with aversion. Thus these three are akusala kamma, and it is mainly caused by cravings for sense pleasures.  Such akusala kamma will only lead one to Apayas – birth in the lower realms.

Comment: Thanks, I found the following sutta to support above.https://suttacentral.net/en/an3.69